# Using a three js render inside a asp.net

Tags: asp.net, three.js

I have a question concerning threejs (WebGL with javascript) and ASP.net. 
I currently am working on a project in which i'am using a 3D render threejs in a html page which works perfectly.
I would like to implement this page inside a asp.net (aspx) in order to use it  with a sql server database.

I created a new asp project in which i put the required files of my project. When i launch my page from the folder (simply by using double click) it works also correctly. But when i copy past the contenent of the page inside an aspx page and i execute the project from the Visual basic, the page is completely empty and the render doesn't work .

Could someone help me resolve this problem ?

Comment: I'am using a dae file 3D render inside my page.

Comment: what is your code ? do you see any errors on browser console ?

Comment: I don't have any error. When i use a simple threejs render without using an 3d model it works perfectly. But when i use the colladaLaoder in order to to use a dae file in my page it looks completly empty